# Retention Rate with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I try to calculate the retention rate with mysql and start with this one:

```
SELECT 
    s_order.ordertime, 
    DATE_SUB(future_orders.ordertime, INTERVAL 90 DAY), 
    count(distinct s_order.userID) as active_users, 
    count(distinct future_orders.userID) as retained_users
FROM s_order
LEFT JOIN s_order as future_orders on
      s_order.userID = future_orders.userID
      AND s_order.ordertime = DATE_SUB(future_orders.ordertime, INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```

This does not work - I get all users are active and therefore I added `DATE_SUB(future_orders.ordertime, INTERVAL 90 DAY),` to the selection criteria to see what is going on. However it returns NULL - but why?

As a reference I did take a look at this explanation:
https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/how-to-calculate-cohort-retention-in-sql.html

My table has a structure like

```
s_orders:
ID | userID | ordertime
```

I would expect a result how many different users have ordered something in general and how many have ordered something again in the last 90 days, to get the retention of the customers.

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong in MySQL?

Comment: I don't follow your question.  You should _edit_ your question and include sample data along with your expected output.  Do this so that others can try to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

DATE_SUB() returns null when the date value is null, so that probably why. Because you are LEFT JOIN-ing, the future_orders record can be null/non-existing